# Disable / read only single tree list node

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I'm using the Devexpress Tree List tool and was wondering if anyone had a way to disable a certain nodes throughout the columns node list. I can disable the entire tree list, or I can turn off certain nodes visibility, both of which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be done like this:

(found [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q327970))

```
    private void treeList_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((TreeList)sender).FocusedNode[columnItemValue].ToString() == "1") //Your condition
            ((TreeList)sender).ActiveEditor.Properties.ReadOnly = true;
    }
```